# Homothety exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, conformal-field-theory

Given the metric

$ds^2=-\rho dt^2-tdtd\rho+t^2d\Omega^2$

How to show that $T=T^{\alpha}\partial_{\alpha}=t\frac{d}{dt}$ is an homothety, so that $(L_T g )_{\mu\nu}=2g_{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Pass to coordinates $\ln t, \rho, \Omega$…

Comment: thank you! solved:)

Comment: @ValterMoretti what is $L_T$ ? A Lie derivative in the $T$ direction? What is the definition of homothety in the context of GR or differential geometry? The definition I found in Wikipedia seems to me like a conformal transformation with a constant conformal factor. But here we have a specific direction $T$

Comment: It is the Lie derivative along $T$. The terminology is improper here as homotheties are defined in affine spaces. Here the space is a manifold.

Comment: @ValterMoretti exactly my point! Besides , as far as I understand an homothety has no privileged direction, here it is only in the $T$ direction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.